# Numpy.where error on pandas dataframe if column contains only None

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with column containing either `float`s, `nan`s, or `None`s. I need to reformat the column so that `float`s are formatted to string with 2 decimals and `nan`s/`None`s are set to empty strings. This works until I hit a case where my column is full of `None`s. Then `numpy.where` does not seem to take into account `df["B"].isnull()` mask even it looks correct when I check its content. As a consequence, `None` are sent to the `round` function which raises a `TypeError`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(
    {"A": [0.1, 0.2423423, 0.345345, None, np.nan], "B": [None, None, None, None, None]}
)
print("1- df :\n", df)
df.iloc[3, 0] = None
print("2- df :\n", df)
print("df.dtypes : \n", df.dtypes)

print("df.isnull() : \n", df.isnull())

df["formatted_A"] = np.where(
    (df["A"].isnull()) | (df["A"].fillna(-999.9) < 0) | (df["A"].astype(str) == ""),
    "",
    df["A"].round(2).astype(str),
)
print("Formatted A- df :\n", df)
df["formatted_B"] = np.where(
    (df["B"].isnull()) | (df["B"].fillna(-999.9) < 0) | (df["B"].astype(str) == ""),
    "",
    df["B"].round(2).astype(str),
)
print("Formatted B- df :\n", df)
```

```py
File "c:\....\dataframe_none_nan_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    df["B"].round(2).astype(str),  ####
  File "C:\....\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2569, in round
    result = self._values.round(decimals)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

I expect `numpy.where` + `pandas.isnull()` mask to work together so my column full of `None`s is transformed into a full column of empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

**Example Code**

The following change to the example code will resolve the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {"A": [0.1, 0.2423423, 0.345345, np.nan, np.nan], "B": [np.nan] * 5}    
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

**Code**

```
df["formatted_B"] = np.where(df["B"].isna(), "", df["B"].round(2).astype(str))
```

`df`

```
    A           B   formatted_B
0   0.100000    NaN 
1   0.242342    NaN 
2   0.345345    NaN 
3   NaN         NaN 
4   NaN         NaN
```

all `None` columns is not float. so cant use round func to all `None` column. but `NaN` is float.

And I would appreciate it if you could make code and question more concise.

Comment: Yes I know None are not float and so cannot be send to round function.
However my understanding is that df[].isnull() detects the None and so in the np.where it should never reach the round() function as it should directly go to first replacement which is ""
A workaround is obviously to replace all the None by np.nan as you do but to me this is a workaround to something that looks like a bug.

Apologize for long code, thought would be clearer for other to see the output in log and see clearly what is unexpected

Comment: I'm not sure what you're struggling with, but even if all bool values are True, you would think that it is not possible to undefined value(for example, df2['B']) to the third argument (False) of np.where. It's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Panda Kim, you made me double-think this and now I see my error. The `df["B"].round(2).astype(str)` is calculated BEFORE the `np.where` is done and not only for the index where `np.where` is `True`.

It does work when I have mixed input in my column (like column A) because pandas automatically convert all the `None` to `np.nan` and as you pointed out `round(np.nan)` is supported. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This misconception of `np.where` is common.  It is a python function, and its arguments are evaluated before their values are passed in.  You pass in arrays or Series, not functions.